Docker Container - No response on https port in Visual Studio 2022 Debug build
i am trying to move an aspnet core application to docker.
Unfortunately i can't get the application run on port https 8081.
I tried several things (see my config below) but when trying to open the app via https in the browser nothing happens (i don't even see an error in the container log files).

I managed to get the app working on http with port 8080 but not on https
Here are my configs so far:
Dockerfile:
I installed additional packages like curl to be able to get more details on running processes and internal http requests on port 8081.
#how to use the asp.net image as base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8081


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
#Install the .NET Core runtime
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk /usr/share/dotnet/sdk
# Instlling the required packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps telnet curl iproute2 wget

The certificate was made with openssl using the bash of the docker image and added to the kestrel config.
Kestrel Config:
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:8081",
      "Certificate": {
        "Path": "/cert/localhost.crt",
        "KeyPath": "/cert/localhost.key"
      }
    }
  }
}

My LaunchSettings in VisualStudio 2022 Version 17.11.0:
 "SDir Docker": {
   "commandName": "Docker",
   "launchBrowser": false,
   "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
   "DockerfileRunArguments": "-p 5001:8081 -p 5000:8080 -v C:\\Users\\dumit\\.aspnet\\https\\:/cert:ro -v D:\\guis\\myservice2dev\\:/frontend:rw -v C:\\temp\\myservice\\database\\:/database:rw -v C:\\temp\\myservice\\plugins\\:/plugins:rw -v C:\\temp\\myservice\\logs\\:/logs:rw -v C:\\temp\\myservice\\secret\\:/secret:rw",
   "environmentVariables": {
     "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
     "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:8081;http://+:8080",
     "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT": "8081",
     "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT": "8080"
   }
 },

The docker-compose does not seem to have an effect, when starting the container in VS 2022 debug mode as it usese some sort of fast mode where lots of things are getting done automatically in the background.
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ../../../
      dockerfile: MyServices/Backend/MyService/Dockerfile
      args:
        nuget_pat: ${AZURE_AUTH_TOKEN}
    ports:
      - "5001:8081"
      - "5000:8080"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: "8081"
      ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT: "8080"
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+:8081;http://+:8080"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: "/cert/localhost.crt"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: "SomeFancyPassword"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\\https\\:/https:ro
      - D:\\guis\\myService2dev\\:/frontend:rw
      - C:\\temp\\myService\\database\\:/database:rw
      - C:\\temp\\myService\\plugins\\:/plugins:rw
      - C:\\temp\\myService\\logs\\:/logs:rw"

When the container is started the ports are configured to map 5001 -> 8081:

After the Docker image build i performed this steps in addition:
# Copy SSL certificates to the container
copied the localhost.crt to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

# Update SSL certificates in the container bash

update-ca-certificates


After enabling the certificates  i finally got a reponse by using curl:
root@9d7ee1765902:/# curl https://localhost:8081
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-n-head="%7B%22lang%22:%7B%221%22:%22en%22%7D%7D">
  <head>
    ...some more html here...
  <script src="/52c0694.js"></script><script src="/77b5243.js"></script></body>
</html>
root@9d7ee1765902:/#

I already enabled the Logs in debug mode and get this output after the curl request:
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
      Hosting started
Api interface started at https://+:8081
info: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService[0]
      Successfully started service MyService
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
      Hosting started
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[39]
      Connection id "0HN5TPLCF9AQ9" accepted.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[1]
      Connection id "0HN5TPLCF9AQ9" started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[3]
      Connection 0HN5TPLCF9AQ9 established using the following protocol: Tls13
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:8081/ - - -
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[0]
      Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/index.html'. Physical path: '/frontend/index.html'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[6]
      Connection id "0HN5TPLCF9AQ9" received FIN.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2[48]
      Connection id "0HN5TPLCF9AQ9" is closed. The last processed stream ID was 1.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[8]
      Connection id "0HN5TPLCF9AQ9" sending RST because: "The client closed the connection."
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:8081/index.html - 200 2450 text/html 65.1364ms
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2[62]
      The connection queue processing loop for 0HN5TPLCF9AQ9 completed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[2]
      Connection id "0HN5TPLCF9AQ9" stopped.

Does anyone has some additional ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue?
Regards meisterd

Seems that my Kestrel section was not correct. Instead of using https://localhost:8081 in the url i ended up by using
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://+:8081"
    }
  },
  "Certificates": {
    "Default": {
      "Path": "/cert/localhost.crt",
      "KeyPath": "/cert/localhost.key"
    }
  }
}

In the logs now i'm getting this message:
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://[::]:8081

